# Can't use Carbon Laravel method in my laravel .blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

In my Controller I get the current date an another date, I send this params to my view.blade:

```
$current_date = Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid');
$second_date  = Carbon::create(2016, 6, 3, 00, 00, 00, 'Europe/Madrid');
```

In my Controller this function works fine:

```
$current_date->lt($second_date) # true
```

But in my blade.php Laravel report this error:
**FatalErrorException in efcb37f79f0e8cb86e0f747997c402d6f7026ada.php line 112:
Call to a member function lt() on string**

I debug my laravel view and the lt() method receives a correct Carbon object

```
Carbon {#361 ▼
  +"date": "2016-06-03 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Madrid"
}
```

what is happening here?

My view code:

```
@foreach ($articles_rows as $articles_row)
            @if($current_date->lt($articles_row['expiration_date']))
                <div class="row">
                ...show articles here
                </div>
            @endif
@endforeach
```

My controller code:

```
$articles_rows = array (

            array(
                'img_src'         => FuImg::asset('img/regalos-para-profesores.jpg'),
                'img_alt'         => 'Regalos para profesores',
                'expiration_date' => Carbon::create(2016, 6, 3, 00, 00, 00, 'Europe/Madrid'),
                'class'           => 'teacher-gifts',
                'articles'        => 
                    # Articulos
                    FotiArticle::getList(array(
                        'fields'     => 'article_id,name,group_id,group,price_pvp_currency,quantity,prices,stock_available',
                        'expand'     => 'group,prices',
                        'article_id' => '2829,186,2875,1728',
                        'order'      => 'PRICE',
                    )),

            ),

            array(
                'img_src'     => Img::asset('img/regalos-ocasiones-especiales.jpg'),
                'img_alt'     => 'Ocasiones especiales',
                'expiration_date' => Carbon::create(2016, 6, 2, 00, 00, 00, 'Europe/Madrid'),
                'class'       => 'wedding',

                'articles'    => Article::getList(array(
                        'fields'     => 'article_id,name,group,price_pvp_currency,quantity,prices,stock_available',
                        'expand'     => 'prices',
                        'article_id' => '1611,4481,50,5345',
                        'order'      => 'PRICE',
                )),
            ),

        );
```

Comment: can you show us your view code?

Comment: I edit the main post with my blade code and my controller code, I get a little example of code. I edit with the complete code.

Comment: Here `$articles_row['expiration_date']` is not carbon object, it's a string

Comment: Ali, when I use <!-- articles rows -->
        @foreach ($articles_rows as $articles_row)
            <?php dd($articles_row['expiration_date']); ?> this return me a object. Not a string

Comment: How do you pass $current_date to the view? This is the one that is a string, not the one passed to lt()

Comment: You need to redefine your `$articles_row['expiration_date']` as a carbon object in order to let it work.

Comment: yes, I pass the current date

Comment: It seems that `$current_date` is not `Carbon` object

Comment: huuk! yes, you have reason

Comment: when I pass the carbon object to view this return a string..how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue over here is with the `$articles_row['expiration_date']` which is considered as a `string` and not an object of `Carbon` class. So the work around over is, you need to create an object of `Carbon` class for your `$articles_row['expiration_date']` using `parse` method like as

```
$current_date->lt(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($articles_row['expiration_date']))
```

Updating OPs answer for Future Users

```
(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($current_date)->lt($articles_row['expiration_date']‌​))
```

OP is facing issue within its own variable `$current_date` as the issue is but logically correct `date` is not `Carbon` object.

Comment: Thanks you, but my $articles_row variable was right, but the $current_date variable Carbon prints me like a string, this works to me:@if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($current_date)->lt($articles_row['expiration_date']))